# VideoCalling using Twilio

Tags: javascript, php, video, twilio, twilio-php

I implemented twilio video calling feature using Twilio Javascript sdk and php. Everything is working fine if I use the old sdk and code in their quick start tutorial on github.(Though it doesn't support IOS). When I use the latest sdk, I'm getting an error and the functionality is no more working.

old Twilio Javascript sdk used in index.html file
`<script src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta2/twilio-video.js"></script>`

new Twilio Javascript sdk used:
`<script src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/v1/twilio-video.min.js"></script>`

And this is the error I see in my console when I use the latest one.
[image]

My `index.js` file.

```
var videoClient;
var activeRoom;
var previewMedia;
var identity;
var roomName;

// Check for WebRTC
if (!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia && !navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
  alert('WebRTC is not available in your browser.');
}

// When we are about to transition away from this page, disconnect
// from the room, if joined.
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', leaveRoomIfJoined);
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('testing');

$.getJSON('./token.php', function (data) {
  identity = data.identity;

  console.log(data);
  // Create a Video Client and connect to Twilio
  videoClient = new Twilio.Video.Client(data.token);
  document.getElementById('room-controls').style.display = 'block';

  // Bind button to join room
  document.getElementById('button-join').onclick = function () {
    roomName = document.getElementById('room-name').value;
    if (roomName) {
      log("Joining room '" + roomName + "'...");

      videoClient.connect({ to: roomName}).then(roomJoined,
        function(error) {
          log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please enter a room name.');
    }
  };

  // Bind button to leave room
  document.getElementById('button-leave').onclick = function () {
    log('Leaving room...');
    activeRoom.disconnect();
  };
});

});

// Successfully connected!
function roomJoined(room) {
  activeRoom = room;

  log("Joined as '" + identity + "'");
  document.getElementById('button-join').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('button-leave').style.display = 'inline';

  // Draw local video, if not already previewing
  if (!previewMedia) {
    room.localParticipant.media.attach('#local-media');
  }

  room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
    log("Already in Room: '" + participant.identity + "'");
    participant.media.attach('#remote-media');
  });

  // When a participant joins, draw their video on screen
  room.on('participantConnected', function (participant) {
    log("Joining: '" + participant.identity + "'");
    participant.media.attach('#remote-media');
  });

  // When a participant disconnects, note in log
  room.on('participantDisconnected', function (participant) {
    log("Participant '" + participant.identity + "' left the room");
    participant.media.detach();
  });

  // When we are disconnected, stop capturing local video
  // Also remove media for all remote participants
  room.on('disconnected', function () {
    log('Left');
    room.localParticipant.media.detach();
    room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
      participant.media.detach();
    });
    activeRoom = null;
    document.getElementById('button-join').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('button-leave').style.display = 'none';
  });
}

//  Local video preview
document.getElementById('button-preview').onclick = function () {
  if (!previewMedia) {
    previewMedia = new Twilio.Video.LocalMedia();
    Twilio.Video.getUserMedia().then(
    function (mediaStream) {
      previewMedia.addStream(mediaStream);
      previewMedia.attach('#local-media');
    },
    function (error) {
      console.error('Unable to access local media', error);
      log('Unable to access Camera and Microphone');
    });
  };
};

// Activity log
function log(message) {
  var logDiv = document.getElementById('log');
  logDiv.innerHTML += '<p>&gt;&nbsp;' + message + '</p>';
  logDiv.scrollTop = logDiv.scrollHeight;
}

function leaveRoomIfJoined() {
  if (activeRoom) {
    activeRoom.disconnect();
  }
}
```

The code in their [github](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) (using quickstart sample as reference) is changed recently and they are using express.js instead, because of which I'm not sure of where is it going wrong. Can someone help me in solving this?

Comment: you should use Twilio.Video.connect(token, { name: 'room-name' })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Between the beta and the released version we changed the way you initialise the library. You no longer use the constructor, which is why you are seeing that error.

Instead you should use `Twilio.Video.connect(token, { name: 'room-name' })` which returns a promise that resolves once you have joined the room.

Check out the [latest Twilio Video JS documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/) for a full code example and to see how to use the version 1 SDK.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented the code just like it is in the link you shared and the issue is resolved. But then I got a new problem because of which I dont see any input box to enter room name or connect button. Neither there is any error in the console something like [this](https://ibb.co/j5WJ2Q).  I uploaded the [code](https://github.com/nasreekar/twilio_php) on github and sharing with you. Can you please check and let me know where have I gone wrong in this. TIA

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd start debugging by logging what happens with `document.getElementById('room-controls')` because if that's not working, your input will not appear.